# Card Carousel Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ionic-framework, ng-controller

I am trying to implement [this animation](http://codepen.io/hanaa/pen/mPmGqP)

Jargon.html

```
<ion-view title="Jargon">
  <ion-content>
    <a class="item" href="#/jargon"></a>

<div class="container">

  <div data-card="4" class="card"><span>Click Me</span></div>
  <div data-card="3" class="card"><span>Click Me</span></div>
  <div data-card="2" class="card"><span>Click Me</span></div>
  <div data-card="1" class="card"><span>Click Me</span></div>
  <div data-card="0" class="card"><span>Click Me</span></div>

</div>
</ion-content>
```

The controller: jargonController.js

```
angular.module('starter.jargonController', ['ionic'])
.controller('jargonCtrl', function (){
    var rotate, timeline;

  rotate = function() {
    return $('.card:first-child').fadeOut(400, 'swing', function() {
      return $('.card:first-child').appendTo('.container').hide();
    }).fadeIn(400, 'swing');
  };

  timeline = setInterval(rotate, 1200);

  $('.card').click(function() {
    return rotate();
  });

});
```

I get this error:

> > Error: $ is not defined @http://localhost:8100/js/controllers
> >
> > ReferenceError: $ is not defined

It is this line that generating the error:

```
    return $('.card:first-child').fadeOut(400, 'swing', function() {
```

what am I missing?

**UPDATE**

This is how I got the layout. It seems like it does not see the css file.[image: Jargon]

Though I made sure to add it here:

```
.state('jargon', {
        url: 'jargon',
        templateUrl: 'templates/jargon.html',
        controller: 'jargonCtrl',
        css: 'css/jarg.css'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing jQuery, if you want to stick using jQuery you can include it https://jquery.com/.

Or you could use a different approch using angular:

```
<ion-view title="Jargon">
  <ion-content>
    <a class="item" href="#/jargon"></a>

    <div class="container">

      <div ng-repeat="n in [0,1,2,3,4]" class="card"><span ng-click="rotate()">Click Me</span></div>

    </div>
    </ion-content>
```

and:

```
angular.module('starter.jargonController', ['ionic'])
        .controller('jargonCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.rotate = function () {
                    //angular code for your animation
                };
            }]);
```

Comment: Thank you. It does not work: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at 'return $('.card:first-child').fadeOut(400, 'swing', function() '

Comment: maybe check the orders of your imports, is jQuery imported before it is called ?

Comment: Thanks I forgot that. I updated my post The error is gone but still I don't get the animation :/

Comment: i'm not sure you can do that: css: 'css/jarg.css' you probably need to import the css file in the <head>

Comment: you are right. I used <script> to import it instead of         <link href="css/jargon.css" rel="stylesheet" /> :D Thx